# Can Months be used in a Discrete Probability Distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions

this concerns one of my projects in Statistics. I am going to measure the frequency of my classmates' birthmonths and going to provide a probability distribution along with it. I am just wondering if it is even possible?

Comment: Sure. Why not?  Why do you think this would be impossible?

Comment: Well, from the somewhat vague discussions from our teacher, I got confused as to what variables I can and can't use. Going back, how do I do it then? Do I assign values to the months (1-12), and continue from there?

Comment: You could use the *names* of months as the "buckets" in which you tally the birth months of your classmates.  That treatment is called *nominal* data.  If you like, you can number the months instead, so that they have the usual calendar order.  This would make the months into *ordinal* data.  There may have been a discussion in your statistics text about the different kinds of data, but for a frequency diagram the way you label the buckets doesn't make a critical difference.

Comment: I think I got it now, lots of thanks for the advice